# Lucene StandardAnalyzer - multiple spaces in the query phrase

Tags: lucene, luke

When creating `org.apache.lucene.document.Document` during indexing I create a `org.apache.lucene.document.StringField` which has multiple spaces together e.g. "ID____45_2013". I use `org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer` for creating the index and for querying it.

When querying index using phrases with multiple spaces e.g. "ID__45_2013" (where _ is a space) I get an empty result.

I have examined my query using [luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) and I realized that multiple spaces are parsed into one space.

What should I do to be able to use multiple spaces in query phrase and get the right result?

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't just multiple spaces.  If you had only single spaces, your query would be tokenized, while the indexed data wouldn't be (since it's created with a `StringField`).  You would be searching for the tokens `ID`, `45`, `2013` vs the single token `ID 45 2013`, which would still get you no results.

You can keep the field as a `StringField`, and set the Analyzer used by the QueryParser to a`KeywordAnalyzer`.  You'dd still need to be careful of query syntax of course, but quoting the string as mentioned should do the trick.

The nicer way to query `StringFields`, I think, is to construct the [`TermQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermQuery.html) yourself.  This removes the need for you to worry about the Analyzer.  Simply create the query like:

```
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("id", "ID   45 2013"));
```

---

You could also, If you wish to use a phrase query like what you've mentioned, you should use a TextField, Analyzed using the same analyzer as you use for querying (`StandardAnalyzer`, in thiscase).  This would provide more free-text searching capability, if that is what you are looking for.  I doesn't sound to me like that's the desired representation, but provided for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

use keyword analyser for both indexing and searching

http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/KeywordAnalyzer.html

Comment: I don't use any analyser for this field. I don't want it. It should be indexed and after that I should be able to find it using phrase query like described in my problem.